# Could I consider that Android WebView equate to Android native browser?

Tags: android, css, webview

I am using Android WebView to play a CSS3 animation.

When I test the animation on GingerBread(2.3), it works fine on Native Browser, but doesn't work on WebView.

Because the native browser is developed base on WebView, so I consider that the function they deal with the css3 animation should be same and I expect the result is same. But the fact is different.

Could anyone explain that?

BTW: I have enable Javascript for WebView, setWebViewClient and setWebChromeClient for WebView.

Comment: they are not the same, there are a lot of tweaks you can do though. Its also a nightmare, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Have you added all the clients? webviewclient,webchromeclient, enabled
 etc.

Comment: javascript,webviewclient,webchromeclient. I enable the three.

Comment: The thing is that webview is generally used to render html and display it as  part of UI,The user wont need to interact with the browser beyond reading it.if you want a full-blown web browser, then you probably want to invoke the Browser application with a URL Intent rather than show it with a webview .